# How do I add two functions in the complete: parameter of ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

This is how my ajax code looks like:

```
   $.ajax({
                        url : ajaxOverallUrl,
                        data : ajaxDataLink,
                        dataType : 'json',
                        type : 'get',
                        async : true,
        success : function(data) {},
        complete: function a{//this contains ajax request 2}, 
function b(){//this contains ajax request 3}
        });
```

I tried the above but did not work. Any other way to do this?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Just put all of your code in one function.

Comment: Because I have two ajax calls to be done in the complete parameter

Comment: So? Just put all of your code in one function.

Comment: @SLaks I see what you are saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the intent ?

```
$.ajax({
  url : ajaxOverallUrl,
  data : ajaxDataLink,
  dataType : 'json',
  type : 'get',
  async : true,
  success : function(data) {},
  complete: function(){a();b();}
});
```

Comment: Yes it is. However adding everything in one function worked for me just fine. Thankyou!